# Right-border doesn't take into account top-margin

Tags: css

My CSS is:

```
p {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 0 0;
    border-color: blue;
    margin-top: 20px
}
```

As you can see from http://jsfiddle.net/dcAQW/1, this creates a white space between the two paragraphs. How can I remove that whitespace (i.e. make it `blue`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `margin` is out of box but `padding` inside the box. So you should use `padding` to get take account.

In this picture border that browser render is the red line. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Switch to padding:

```
p {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 0 0;
    border-color: blue;
    padding-top: 20px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dcAQW/3/

Answer (score 1):

Margin is not included in the inside of the border in the box-model, but padding is. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) for more details on the box model

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is to add a div over the paragraphs so the css will be like the code below:

```
div
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 0 0;
    border-color: blue;
}
p {

    padding-top: 20px
}
```

See  http://jsfiddle.net/dcAQW/3/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the box model (as described by @Mohsen), you want padding on the paragraph and not margin. Also, it's more concise and readable to write it like this:

```
p {
    border-right: 15px solid blue;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```